# Issue while importing CSV file from List Manager - Import Contact Wizard

Tags: list-manager

Using the List Manager on Import contact wizard on `Sitecore 9.0 Update 1`, I have uploaded my CSV files. In the summary tab I can see that "Contact expected to be imported" count is perfectly fine.  After clicking on finish button. I am seeing a warning message saying

> Please note that contacts in the list are currently being indexed, so
>   not all contacts are available to view at this time.

I waited for long even a day as well, but I am not able to see my contacts.

Please can somebody point out the root cause of this?

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: how many contacts you have on your csv?

Comment: I have only 5 contacts and all are expected to import as you can see the screenshot,

Comment: is it your searchindexer and solr running?

Comment: Yes. these are running fine.

Comment: Did you just import contacts? Or did you create a list? If you created a list, can you show that list in your question?  Your contacts are probably there. But until they have stored interactions, they wont show in experience profile.

Comment: please check the listmanager.aspx page under sitecore/admin and try to rebuild the index. You will find the difference if index and DB is not in sync.

Comment: @NSP, listmanager.aspx does not exist in Sitecore 9.0 update 1. Even it does not present in Sitecore 8.2 as well.

Comment: @PeteNavarra Just imported contacts

Comment: I suggest to check the XConnect search indexer logs.

Comment: I am not seeing any thing in xConnect

Comment: Can you add here content of your CSV file? Are there any special characters in names? Could you also update question with screenshot of "Map" tab when you are importing?

Comment: Have you tried to import more then one csv file? I have done it in last couple of weeks minimum 5 times without any issues

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Any pointers to resolve this issue?

Comment: In Sitecore 9 Update-1.

Comment: I am also having this issue - Azure, Scaled - Sitecore 9 Update-1